# Google Sheets Dropdown Selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help from someone who is pretty familiar with Google Sheets. As you can see in the example table, I would like to change certain values ​​in a range based on a table when selecting the dropdown menu. I've tried a few things now, but can't get it the way I'd like to.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17KENpYebYwkZ_7QRHH0D-jT354ETZKUTvZB9ydGfvGE/edit?usp=sharing

I tried it with

```
VLOOKUP
```

But seems not the best way.

I'm trying now about 3 hours to get this work, any help would be amazing.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the end result should look like? Looks like you want to use FILTER and TRANSPOSE.

Comment: I tried with FILTER and TRANSPOSE but the result can't find a result, maybe i'm doing wrong.
But to explain, if I select the item from B2, the content from B5:C25 should be filtert into M4:Q5 with only the values and names where a value is in. I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution i've found what is working for me, thanks for your comment @IMTheNachoMan

```
=transpose(unique(filter(B5:B25, C5:C25<>"")))
```

This gives me the result I need.